# PyQt equal length strings with whitespaces have different display length

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt5

In `PyQt5`, I found that equal length strings with whitespaces have different final display length:

[image]

while the **desired output** should be like:

```
123456789
1 3456789
1  456789
1   56789
```

I found this issue not only exists in `QComboBox`, but also in other multi-row widgets. Fixing length, such as `{:15s}`, also cause the issue.

**Is there a way to display as the desired output?**

A minimal example of the described issue:

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QComboBox, QMainWindow
import sys

class Window(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self): 
        super().__init__() 
        self.combo_box = QComboBox(self)
        a = ["123456789", "1 3456789", "1  456789", "1   56789"]
        self.combo_box.addItems(a)
        self.show()

App = QApplication(sys.argv) 
window = Window()
sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: Your combobox needs to use a monospace font, so that each character has the same width.

Comment: It should be pointed out that this is *not* an issue, it is *not* related to PyQt and has nothing to do with "multi-row widgets". This is a *typical* **feature** of any variable length font. Have you ever noticed that "ooo" has a different width than "lll"? Consequently, "o o" will have a different width than "ooo" (as "l l" and "o o" cannot obviously have the same width). This applies to *any* character, including white spaces (which are usually thinner than numbers) and punctuation, and it's also true for most fonts even with numbers: "8" is *not* always as large as "1".

Comment: Hi, Maurizio. Thank you for pointing that out. No, I initially did not think that was a font issue. What made me think that is because my frequenly-used programming environment (Vim, Sublime, Notepad, Windows Python console, gnome terminal...) all indicate 'ooo' have the same width as 'iii'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The misalignment is caused by the font as it doesn't give you the same space between the letters and the spaces. The solution is to use a font like "monospace":

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QFont

font = QFont("monospace")
self.combo_box.setFont(font)
```

Comment: To add on, for aesthetic purpose, especially when there are Russian-like characters, download and add "Consolas" font instead of `monospace`.